# How convert a string value to number - Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpql

I need to concat 2 colunms and convert the value to number, above it is the code:

```
SELECT T FROM TABLE T WHERE CAST(substring(replace(T.versionSince, '.', ''), 1, 1)+'.'+substring(replace(T.versionSince, '.', ''), 2) as  DOUBLE) <= :version
```

It is possible to do it with Hibernate ?

Answer (score 0):

You can concat and convert, you can also substring, but you cannot replace:

**Update**

This is how your cast should look like:

```
cast(
     (concat(
              substring(u.firstName,1,locate('.', u.firstName))
              , concat(
                        substring(
                                  u.firstName
                                  ,1+locate('.', u.firstName, locate('.', u.firstName))
                                  ,locate('.', u.firstName, 1+locate('.', u.firstName, locate('.', u.firstName)))- (1+locate('.', u.firstName, locate('.', u.firstName)))
                                 )
                       , substring(
                                   u.firstName
                                   , 1+locate('.', u.firstName, 1+locate('.', u.firstName, locate('.', u.firstName)))
                                   , length(u.firstName)
                                  )
                       )
             )
      ) as float
    )
```

**Additionally:**

- This works for strings like : "1.2.3"
- The cast(.. as float).. you may need to use 'double', 'real' or 'numeric'  depending on your underlying database
- If you happen to have a bit different format on some rows, then you have play with a variation of my query..
- The bottom line is that you cannot use REPLACE in hql.. such a function does not exist.. you have to use a combination of SUBSTRING AND LOCATE. It is not as easy as it would be with REPLACE but you can pull it off if you put in the effort.

Comment: But I need remove remove the dots, I just can keep  the first dot, because my number for version needs to be a double.

Comment: give me an example

Comment: I have 2 column with '1.2.3' and '1.2.5'  I need convert both ro compare with 1.20 (double or decimal)

Comment: I have updated the post. It will work with '1.2.3' format - like entries. Try it out

Comment: But the function cast don't exists in hibernate, no?

Comment: HQL supports CAST (if underlying database supports it)